# Getting the selected radio button inside OnClick for a button

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I am building a simple app
which allow the user to enter his name and select the radio button "with name"
and a toast shows , Hello Name

and the other radio for guest to show hello guest , so How I can get the selected radio inside the OnClick do I need to get them from FindViewByID ??

here my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        //getting the selected radio if its radio 0
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello Guest", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //getting the selected radio if its radio 1
    EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Hello " + txt.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Define radio button as you do for button in onCreate() and get the state of that radio button.

Comment: This is not your actual code, as you can clearly see after I reformatted it - you have mismatched braces (see the last two lines of the code). This code won't compile. Also, you're only checking for `id.button1` and then always retrieving `editText1` and using it in a `Toast.makeText` call.

Comment: this is my code , but I changed few stuff , the only problem I am facing , is to get the selected radio inside the OnClick , the edittext will not work it

Comment: I thought I can get the status of the radio by isChecked ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        //YOUR CODE HERE
    }
});
```

Put that in onCreate() and see how that works out for you. Have you also tried seeing if the Id of View v passed into onClick is actually the correct view? To see this, use [log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to check the Id.

Answer (score 0):

better you directly check the radio button state on button click listener:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) 

{
if(v == button)
{

if(rb1.isChecked() == true)
Toast.makeText(this, "Hello"+rb1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

if(rb2.isChecked() == true)
Toast.makeText(this, "Hello"+rb2.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

where

```
rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.optname);
rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.optguest);
```

FOR [MORE](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-radiobutton-example)